# Section name for class project reports, theses, short essays

Tags: website

In my personal website, I'd like to have a section for class project reports, theses, and short essays I've written. I'm thinking about naming the section "Other Publications" or "Other Papers", but I'm not sure if these count as "Publications" or "Papers". Do they count? If not, is there an appropriate term?

(Since it's a personal website, I don't think it's so important to get every detail correct, but it would be nice to get it correct nevertheless.)

Comment: I would go for "Documents" or perhaps "Other Documents", not because calling them publications is technically incorrect, but it's likely to be not what  academics think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes people call such a collection "Other Writings" or "Other Works".

If they haven't been published, they're not publications.  And most academics think of "paper" as synonymous with "published paper", so that term is likely to be misleading as well.

Comment: Sounds good.  In menus, I like short -- so I'd go with "Other."

Comment: "Other work" was my thought as well.